# How listeners work in java, where do they reside, what is it memory management?

Tags: java, jvm

How Listeners works in JVM? Where they reside? What keeps track of them? I tried searching but couldnt find any references

Comment: The main thing to realize about listeners in Java is that they're not special in any way.

Comment: Does each listener run as a thread??? Does it have any port?

Comment: Listeners are just interfaces they get called on specific action like click

Comment: @Rajesh there is a separate event thread, that is always checking for events. Whenever it finds an event, it tells all of the objects that are listening for it that this happened. You absolutely do not have a thread for every listener though. The event thread is going to run regardless

Comment: @Cruncher does it mean that it uses some notifyall kind of mechanism??? If so does this whole concept also have wait mechanism?

Comment: Can someone show me how to visualize this Listeners concept?

Answer (score 3):

From Oracle's [Introduction to Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html):

> The event model, which you saw at its simplest in the preceding example, is quite powerful and flexible. Any number of event listener objects can listen for all kinds of events from any number of event source objects. For example, a program might create one listener per event source. Or a program might have a single listener for all events from all sources. A program can even have more than one listener for a single kind of event from a single event source.

[image]

> Multiple listeners can register to be notified of events of a particular type from a particular source. Also, the same listener can listen to notifications from different objects.

Comment: I could understand(little) listeners in the context of AWT and SWING but is there any other places where listeners can be used? Any example in that context? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, you can use listeners anywhere you want.  Read this Event Listener article of mine for a fuller explanation.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=150

Comment: Link is not working!!

Comment: @acearch: [Event Listener](https://web.archive.org/web/20130507164841/http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=150) article.